# How to get a list of valid X11 names for characters

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am trying to customize my own keyboard layout.
I have been messing around with the files in:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/
```

I see that, e.g. `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` contains:

```
...
    key <TLDE> { [        grave,   asciitilde,      dead_tilde,       asciitilde ] };
    key <AE01> { [            1,       exclam,      exclamdown,      onesuperior ] };
    key <AE02> { [            2,           at,       masculine,      twosuperior ] };
    key <AE03> { [            3,   numbersign,     ordfeminine,    threesuperior ] };
    key <AE04> { [            4,       dollar,            cent,         sterling ] };
    key <AE05> { [            5,      percent,        EuroSign,              yen ] };
...
```

How could I get a list of the valid *names* for the non-single-char (special?) characters, like e.g. `dollar`, `masculine`, etc.?

---

## EDIT

I have found this:

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap

and this:

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_keysyms

but it is not complete, and does not necessarily reflect what is on my system.
I am rather looking for a way to know in which file(s) is this info stored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at `/usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h`.

I am reasonably sure that those correspond exactly to the names used in `xkb` if you ignore the leading `XK_` in the definitions (see the comments at the beginning of the file), but I've never verified this myself.